# Redirect add to cart button to checkout page for 1 specific landing page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have created a landing page on our WooCommerce shop that is built with the Divi page builder.

On this landing page we have added an add-to-cart button. Now we would like to redirect this specific add-to-cart button directly to the checkout, but keep the other add-to-cart buttons on the shop and archive pages linking to the cart.

This is the code we have now in our functions.php.

**First version**

```
// get the id of the post/page based on the request uri.
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$post_id = url_to_postid($url);

// the id of the specific page/post.
$specific_post_id = 6356; 

// check if the requested post id is identical to the specific post id.
if ($post_id == $specific_post_id) {

    
    // add function to redirect the add to cart button to the checkout
    add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'magma_add_to_cart_redirect');
    function magma_add_to_cart_redirect() {
        
     global $woocommerce;
        
     $magma_redirect_checkout = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();  
     return $magma_redirect_checkout;
        
    }
}
```

**Second version**

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'magma_add_to_cart_redirect');

function magma_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
        
        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $post_id = url_to_postid($url);
        
        $specific_post_id = 6356; 
    
        if ($post_id == $specific_post_id) {    
            global $woocommerce;
            
            $magma_redirect_checkout = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();   
            return $magma_redirect_checkout;
        }       
}
```

The two parts of the code - recognizing the page & the redirect function - are working properly if they are separate from each other, for example

- If I put an echo in the if-clause, then this echo only shows on the page with ID  **6356** so this works
- If I trigger the function **magma_add_to_cart_redirect** outside the if-clause, ALL the add-to-cart buttons redirect to the checkout, so this clearly works too

However, when put together, I can't seem to get it to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Help is much appreciated!

Kr,
Jan

Comment: When the actual add-to-cart _request_ is performed, is `$post_id` actually set to what you think it should be …?

Comment: @CBroe No value returns, I'm afraid.

I changed the code a bit, so 'recognizing the page'-part is now in the function, see original post.

In that case, `$post_id` is recognized, but the result stays the same.

Comment: What does that mean, “result stays the same”? If you replaced the condition checking on the post id in your second version with just `if (true)`, is it then working for all buttons again?

Comment: @Cbroe Correct! If I replace the condition with `if (true)` in my second version, then ALL the add-to-cart buttons are redirecting to the checkout.

Comment: That makes no sense, combined with what you said earlier, _“In that case, $post_id is recognized”_ - **if** `$post_id` did _actually_ contain `6356` now, then there is no plausible reason whatsoever, why this should not work. So the most logical explanation is, that it actually doesn’t. How _exactly_ have you verified this?

Comment: @CBroe I did an echo of the `$post_id` in the second version and I saw the `$post_id` was `6356` in that case. When I did that in the first version, no value returned in my echo. I'm sorry if that's not the right way to check, my knowledge of PHP is basic, to say the least.

Comment: Just to be clear, that was _after_ you clicked the add to cart button, correct? Can you do a `var_dump($post_id, $specific_post_id, $post_id == $specific_post_id);` and show what that results in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234197/discussion-between-jan-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

For the people landing on this page and needing an answer, I found a different approach to solve this.

On the landing page - instead of using the WooCommerce add-to-cart-button from Divi - I've added the WooCommerce **shortcode** of an add-to-cart-button, like this

`[add_to_cart id="4088" show_price="false" /]`

You can find more information about WooCommerce shortcodes here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

In my case, this button didn't require the price to be shown next to it (price is positioned somewhere else on the page), so I've added the value `false` to the attribute `show_price`.

This results in a working add-to-cart-button that adds the product with ID `4088` to the cart with AJAX.

To redirect this button to the checkout, I've added a redirect on this button set in a timeout to be triggered after 1s (after the AJAX is completed), like this.

```
jQuery(".ajax_add_to_cart").click( function (){
   setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "https://xxx/nl/winkelkarretje/";
   }, 1000);

});
```

It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it did the trick for me, so maybe it can help others too :).